# Sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

There is one definition of sum of subspaces in book "Linear Algebra Done right"

Suppose $U_1,U_2...U_m$ are subspaces of $V$. Then:

$U_1+U_2+U_3...+U_m:=\{u_1+u_2+...+u_m: u_1 \in U_1...u_m \in U_m\}$. Then there are two examples. Let $U:=\{(x,0,0) \in F^3:x\in F\}$ and $W:=\{(0,y,0)\in F^3:y \in F\}$, then

$U+W=\{(x,y,0):x,y \in F\}$ it's easy to show. But I can't understand next one. Suppose

$U:=\{(x,x,y,y) \in F^4:x,y \in F\}$ and $W:=\{(x,x,x,y)\in F^4:x,y \in F\}$, then

$U+W=\{(x,x,y,z) \in F^4:x,y,z \in F\}$ but how did we get it?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez yes. I didn't understand, why for example at the third place of this sum we have $y$, but not $x$? Or some $b \in F$?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ in $U$ are not the same in $W$. When you want to sum change the parameters. For Example, take : $$U = \{(x, x, y, y): x, y \in F\} \text{ and } W = \{(z, z, z, t): z, t \in F\}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably helpful to change the letters used in the elements to see what's going on.  An arbitrary element of $U$ looks like $(a, a, b, c)$, and an arbitrary element of $W$ looks like $(d, d, d, e)$, for some numbers $a, b, c, d, e$.  Thus a general element of $U+W$ will look like $(a+d, a+d, b+d, c+e)$.  Now observe that, since $a$ and $d$ can be anything, so can $a+d$. $b+d$ and $c+e$ can also be anything, but don't have to be the same as $a+d$ or as each other.  Thus the general element of $U+W$ will have the form $(x, x, y, z)$ for some $x, y, z$.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me!